# Add custom canonical for front page - Yoast

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a custom url for the front page using YOAST. I'm trying this approach but it doesn't do anything, can you help me?

```
function design_canonical($url) {
    global $post;
    $url == ( 'www.cator.com/cator/');
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'design_canonical' );
```

any idea where is the problem?
thanks

Answer (score 1):

You first need to check if your page is home or not which you can check through `is_home()`

```
function design_canonical($url) {

    if (is_home()) {
        return 'your-custom-url.com'; //Enter here your custom url
    } else {
        return $url;
    }
}

add_filter( 'wpseo_canonical', 'design_canonical' );
```

Comment: I add this but it still adds the main canonical and not the canonical url that it put in "your-custom-url.com". Do you know why is not working?